# Why might my code take a few ms to run but clients take a long time to get an answer from the server?

Tags: performance, iis, azure

We have a web role hosted in azure on a couple of small machines, which we post some xml (couple of kb) to. The web role then calls another WCF service (another web role in the same deployment, again small instances) which does a bit of processing and returns a guid, which the first web role returns to the client.

When we run load tests and time the code in the post method, it generally runs quickly (eg 600ms) but the client (SoapUI in this case set up not to include sending and receiving data time) sometimes reports that the method call took almost 6000ms.  This seems to be backed up by the IIS logs.  This might happen for 1% of calls.

How can I find out where this time has gone as I don't seem to have any other code that we are responsible for to time?

Edit to add some more info.

We have done some profiling of this (simple, by starting a stopwatch doing something and ending it and logging the results) and all of the code that we have control over, from the entry point of the post to the moment we return the results is what was taking 600ms, but soap UI reported almost 6000ms for the same call (identified by the guid returned).

Comment: Is this from IIS sleeping? Once it warms up, is it fast again? I bet this is your issue. I recall the idle timeout is set to something like 10 minutes by default. Could be wrong on that detail, though. You can change this with startup scripts or even with C# in your OnStart if you want.

Comment: its not going idle as this is a few requests in the middle of a load test, so everything is fine then all of a sudden we will get a batch of tests which exhibit this behaviour

Comment: Another large possibility is how you're hosting WCF and how it's configured. There are many possible ways to configure concurrency settings in ways that cause blocking. Otherwise, I'd start doing some profiling to identify the exact location for the delay whether it's in your code, in WCF, in IIS/WAS, the internet, etc. Ultimately, are the latencies random or are they related to one another? For instance, do ALL calls finish almost simultaneously once the first one that hits the delay finishes? Are there shared resources? etc.